# How could I do line breaks (/n or /r/n) on Messaging.SingleEmailMessage PlainTextBody?

Tags: apex, email-template, string, formatting, send-email

I know this question is asked before and could found in the below links, 
(I am posting this as I want to post my code with some changes to the solutions provided in the below links.)

[PlainText email doesn't line break as expected](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46254/plaintext-email-doesnt-line-break-as-expected)

[Send Email with the body formatted](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/58329/send-email-with-the-body-formatted)

I found the following code in a mentioned links above and tried though it doesn't work,
What am I doing wrong here?

```
String plainTextBody = '';
plainTextBody += 'Confirmed Late Delivery is changed to unticked \n';
plainTextBody += 'Delivered Status is changed to a value that is not Delivered Late \n';
plainTextBody += 'Late Code is changed \n';
plainTextBody += 'or Late Code Subcategory is changed \n\n';

String[] toRecipients = new List<String> {'hasantha@com.au'};
String[] ccRecipients = new String[] {};
String[] bccRecipients = new String[] {};
String subject = 'test sub';
String body = plainTextBody;

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(1);
email.setToAddresses(toRecipients);
email.setCcAddresses(ccRecipients);
email.setbccAddresses(bccRecipients);
email.setSubject(subject);
email.setPlainTextBody(body);

System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,'** entered sendEmail, to:' + toRecipients + ' cc:' + ccRecipients + ' bcc:' + bccRecipients + ' subject:' + subject + ' body:' + body);

Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
```

**Below is the content of the received email**

> Confirmed Late Delivery is changed to unticked Delivered Status is changed to a value that is not Delivered Late Late Code is changed or Late Code Subcategory is changed

Thanks in-advance!

Comment: just now tested above code. line breaking working for me.

Comment: It's weird this doen't work for me. I ran this through anonymous apex run.

Comment: I replaced the first 5 lines with String plainTextBody = '';
plainTextBody += ' Confirmed Late Delivery is changed to unticked \n ';
plainTextBody += ' Delivered Status is changed to a value that is not Delivered Late \n ';
plainTextBody += ' Late Code is changed \n ';
plainTextBody += ' or Late Code Subcategory is changed \n\n '; AND it works! Do not know the exact reason. It doen't make sense of giving space(s) between each value assignments allowing the new line character to be functioned. Still a question for me!

Comment: Can you pls add your exact code which are giving issue ? I am not able to replicate the issue by giving spaces.

Comment: @Ratan Don't misunderstand my comment explanation, the code with the original post does not work for me (you said it worked for you), secondly I gave some spaces besides the newline character and it worked for me.  What is the reason for this?

Comment: no idea why this is not working. I will look into this in my free time. If I will found something will let you know.

Comment: With your posted code above, in Outlook 2013, Outlook displays as you show in yellow with a prompt to restore the line breaks - clicking the prompt displays 4 lines; Gmail displays as 4 lines